# Visual Basic: Slot machine values all return the same values

Tags: vb.net, random

I have attempted to create a simple slot machine in visual basic windows form creator. Here is my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim List1 = New String() {"Banana", "Cherry", "Watermelon", "Bell", "Skull", "Apricot"}
        Dim List2 = New String() {"Banana", "Cherry", "Watermelon", "Bell", "Skull", "Apricot"}
        Dim List3 = New String() {"Banana", "Cherry", "Watermelon", "Bell", "Skull", "Apricot"}
        Dim rn1 = New Random()
        Dim rn2 = New Random()
        Dim rn3 = New Random()
        Dim x As Integer = 0
        While x < 30
            Dim Choice = List1(rn1.Next(0, List1.Count))
            Dim Choice2 = List2(rn2.Next(0, List2.Count))
            Dim Choice3 = List3(rn3.Next(0, List3.Count))

            Select Case Choice
                Case "Banana"
                    Slot1.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Banana
                Case "Cherry"
                    Slot1.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Cherry
                Case "Watermelon"
                    Slot1.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Watermelon
                Case "Skull"
                    Slot1.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Skull
                Case "Apricot"
                    Slot1.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Apricot
                Case "Bell"
                    Slot1.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Bell
            End Select
            Select Case Choice2
                Case "Banana"
                    Slot2.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Banana
                Case "Cherry"
                    Slot2.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Cherry
                Case "Watermelon"
                    Slot2.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Watermelon
                Case "Skull"
                    Slot2.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Skull
                Case "Apricot"
                    Slot2.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Apricot
                Case "Bell"
                    Slot2.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Bell
            End Select
            Select Case Choice3
                Case "Banana"
                    Slot3.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Banana
                Case "Cherry"
                    Slot3.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Cherry
                Case "Watermelon"
                    Slot3.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Watermelon
                Case "Skull"
                    Slot3.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Skull
                Case "Apricot"
                    Slot3.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Apricot
                Case "Bell"
                    Slot3.Image = Fruit_Machine.My.Resources.Resources.Bell
            End Select

            x = x + 1
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

This does work: each outcome of the slot machine is randomised... to an extent. I am aware that the code is overcomplicated but this is simply a test project and nothing that anyone else is going to see. Being new to VB I understand that this code is probably... messy. However, the main issue arises when the results of the fruit machine show that all 3 slots are the same value. I.E.

[This displays that the result is all 3 skulls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH1V3.png)

I need a solution to this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will be because each instance of `Random` is using the same seed (system time), try using the same instance of `Random` and calling `Next` on it e.g.

```
    Dim myRandom = New Random()

    Dim x As Integer = 0
    While x < 30
        Dim Choice = List1(myRandom.Next(0, List1.Count))
        Dim Choice2 = List2(myRandom.Next(0, List2.Count))
        Dim Choice3 = List3(myRandom.Next(0, List3.Count))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instantiating three `Random` objects in quick succession is causing them to get the same seed value from the system clock, so they're all producing the same sequence.  Use the `Random(Int32)` constructor with different seeds to get three different sequences of random values, or just use one `Random` object to generate all of your values.  From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) (emphasis added):

> To produce different sequences of random numbers, you can make the seed value time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new instance of Random. The parameterized Random(Int32) constructor can take an Int32 value based on the number of ticks in the current time, whereas the parameterless Random() constructor uses the system clock to generate its seed value. **However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.**